# jquery click to find position - returns enveloping div not stated div

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {    
$('.map').click(function(e) {
    var posX = $(this).position().left,posY = $(this).position().top; 
    $(".formX").val((e.pageX - posX))
    $(".formY").val((e.pageY - posY))
});
});
```

to find a location within a map, however the results returned are for the position of the div that envelopes the item rather than the stated class

http://www.djnovainmobiliaria.com.mx/example/

when I remove the divs it works fine and gives the co-ordinates within the div no matter the position on the page

http://www.djnovainmobiliaria.com.mx/example/without.html

I can't figure this out despite hours of changing CSS z-index, positioning etc.

Comment: Try putting `pointer-events:none` for the parent?

Comment: Sounds like there might be a bubble issue.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: e.stopPropagation() ??

Comment: Is it me or is it working with Y just not the X.

Comment: @Leeish probably because the wrapping divs have the same height as the map but differrent widths

Comment: Leeish - it's returning the enclosing div top left position - which at the moment is 0 so it seems fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to use `.offset()` instead of `.position()`.

From the [JQuery documentation for `.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/):

> The .position() method allows us to retrieve the current position of
>   an element relative to the offset parent. Contrast this with
>   .offset(), which retrieves the current position relative to the
>   document.

From the [JQuery documentation for `event.pageX`](http://api.jquery.com/event.pageX/):

> The mouse position relative to the left edge of the document.

Comment: That's the puppy! Been driven crazy by this for hours as the jsfiddle I'd been testing with with worked perfectly well.